# control what iframe sees as window.top?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

There is a web application that works by loading different iframes into iself. It provides some code that the child iframes hook into.

The child iframes access window.top instead of window.parent and are out of my control.  Everything works fine.

Now, I want to include THAT APPLICATION as an iframe in another site.  That application does not need any "parent" or "top" access to this other site.  However, when that application's child iframes do window.top, they end up with the "top" being the other site, rather than the application.

Ideally, I want window.top (in the child iframes) to mean "that application" and not "the other site that included that application in iframe".

It seems window.top is read only.  What are my options?

EDIT: I have full access to that application, and the other site.  It's only the child frames within that application that are fixed.

As example of possible solutions:

1. Have that application insert fake window object into child frames with .top referring to that application.
2. Pass all the files through a server-side proxy that rewrites the code of the child frames dynamically each time.

EDIT 2: So the "solution" is to replace .top with .parent, or .parent.parent if further nested in a frameset (the case some times).  For now, I can do this when user uploads their HTML/js (which gets iframed) to CMS of that application. Then code never goes up all the way to the other site. Still looking for more options not involving modifying files on disk.

Comment: You can not control that.

Comment: I have the same issue - a page with iframes that uses window.top, and I want to put the whole thing into an iframe...

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what window.top is, it will always be the top window. If you have access to the code of the page you are embedding your application in, then you may be able to pass on the info to it from your application (depending on what you are using window.top for).

If you just need to read some info from it or have it listen for some event, you could use `postmessage` to relay the info from the application frame to the parent frame (the one that is being detected as `window.top`, but otherwise you are out of luck

Comment: actually, I saw someone make his own window object to replace the window object and set top to something else.  So there are options.  Also writing code to download each item as text, dynamically change references to window.top, and eval it.  I am not out of luck. I'm looking for the best solution.

Comment: I would not recommend either of those things